# How to apply for Schengen visa after expiration of residence permit?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens

I am a Philippine passport holder and currently residing in Hungary as a student. I have been issued a residence permit here in Hungary which is valid until June 30, 2019. I am planning to take a short (15 days) vacation with my family, who are coming over from the Philippines, after finishing my studies by June 2019 and would like to visit other Schengen countries by July. In sum, I just wanted to extend my stay here in Europe for a couple of days, for tourism purposes, after the expiration of my residence permit.

Is it possible for a third country national to apply for a Schengen visa (Visa C since less than 90 days) while currently holding a residence permit issued by Hungary?

I tried contacting the Austrian Embassy in Bratislava that processes Schengen visa applications since Vienna is my planned point of entry and where we intended to stay the longest. However, I got confused with one of the requirements mentioned on their website,as written below:

"Original and copy of Schengen-Residence permit or long term national visa issued by Schengen member state: **The current residence permit, issued from the country you are staying, needs to be at least 3 months valid, after your requested visa expires.** If the applicant is planning to move to another country – other than the one the residence permit was issued before – please bring any kind of proof"

Since my residence permit in Hungary will expire by June 30,2019 and I can only lodge my application at the earliest three months before my intended date of travel which is June 30, 2019, my residence permit will no longer be valid for 3 months by the time I lodge my application which I intend to do around April 2019. So, it is impossible for me to meet this requirement. I sent an email to the Embassy to clarify and the response was that I cannot apply for a visa and there are no other option/s to apply for a Schengen visa.

I am totally confused since with respect to the abovementioned requirement, I need not apply for a Schengen visa anyway if my residence permit in Hungary would still be valid after June. I understand that should my residence permit still be effective, I can still freely enter other Schengen countries. Thus, if the requirement above is to have a residence permit that is valid for 3 months upon application of Schengen visa and the Visa C that I am applying for will only be valid also for 90 days, there is no point in actually applying for a Schengen visa.

Hope I was able to lay down the details clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best chance is to [extend](http://www.bmbah.hu/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=70&Itemid=824&lang=en#) your permit. Asking for a tourist visa immediately after your other one expires would raise too many red flags. Especially because your family comes here as well.
Just [call](http://www.bmbah.hu/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=32&Itemid=1168&lang=en#) them, and ask how to do it.

One more thing: when I got my degree, the ceremony where I got it was a lot (I think months) after my last exam. Ask your school when this is, your family might want to see you get your degree, and this may give you one more reason to get a short extension. (based on distances, I assume you study somwhere in Győr, but I don't know enough to tell when your "diplomaosztó" will be)